# Compress images client-side with ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fileapi, ng-file-upload

I've got an AngularJS app that uses `ng-file-upload` to upload images to my server. I want to be able to compress, or at least resize images prior to uploading them to my server. I've been researching ways to do this and so far this [ng-image-compress](https://github.com/sammychl/ng-image-compress) directive seems like the most viable approach. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't seem to be compatible with `ng-file-upload`. I managed to pull it into my app as a dependency, but when I upload a file, it's not compressed prior to being uploaded. The readme on the project repo offers little guidance on its usage. Are there other approaches I can take to compress the image client-side before it's uploaded with `ng-file-upload`?

Comment: If you just want to resize the photos you can use ngf-resize directive from ng-file-upload.

Comment: Didn't realize it was there. I was running an older version. Just updated to the latest and it works great. Thanks